# Remember selected item on postback in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, drop-down-menu

I'm fixing an old website at my work. I'm kind of new at this job and I'm currently looking for a way to remember the selected item in an xslt file on postback, I don't really know anything about xslts so I'm asking here.

drop down I want to remember:

```
<select id="filtertype" class="subscriptionselector" onchange="changeFilter()">
    <option value="present">Present</option>
    <option value="notpresent">Not Present</option>
    <option value="noreply">No reply</option>
</select>
```

what do I have to put in my code so then when a postback happens (because a button is pressed) that the filtertype doesn't get reset every time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you try to keep a state between two XSLT calls. It's not possible. But you can add a parameter (possibly a node), that you pass to your XSLT with a value you keep in memory between two calls. For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="lastNode" as="node()"/>
    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Lets say I pass this value, what do I do then? I really don't know anything about xslts >_>

Comment: could you please explain : the kind of XML input you have for your XSLT and what do you expect as output. Then I can tell you how to use the parameter value. Besides that, what version of XSLT do you use 1 or 2 ?